# Unique formula for even and odd for this sequence

Tags: algorithm, sequence

Before compiling my code, I got stuck while generating a general formula. Can anyone help me get the general formula of the sequence below?

```
when n=3 the value is 0
when n=4 the value is 1
when n=5 the value is 0
when n=6 the value is -1
when n=7 the value is 0
when n=8 the value is 1
when n=9 the value is 0
when n=10 the value is-1
when n=11 the value is 0
when n=12 the value is 1
when n=13 the value is 0
 when n=14 the value is -1 etc
```

I got part of the formula but I couldn't determine what exactly should go where my question marks (???) are,

```
|(-1)^n -1|/2 + (-1)^[n(???/2)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one general formula of the many, leveraging the periodicity of the sequence.

[image: trigonometric approach]

[See the sequence on OEIS (*A056594*)](https://oeis.org/A056594).

---

Another representation more along the lines of what you were attempting is using two "*indicators*", the first handling the parity and the second the sign for each even number.

[image: indicator approach]

Answer (score 2):

I hope this satisfies your request,

```
( (-1)^n + (1)^n )/2 *((-1)^(n/2))

intuition,
        -1  for n=6,10,14 ..
        0   for n=3,5,7,9 .. 
        1   for n=4,8,12 ..
```

the first term reduces to zero whenever power is odd .
in case of even power , we observe `-1` has `n/2` powers as odd .

Comment: There's no need to raise 1 to the power of n in your approach, anyhow nice answer!

Comment: I agree , somehow overlooked it :)

Comment: In case you aren't aware - if you choose to you can always edit your answer with the tool-tip underneath it. Furthermore, you might find the [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) useful for future answers. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems simpler (to me, anyway):

```
((n+1)%2)*(2-(n+1)%4)
```